# Check for Unique character in a string (java)

Tags: java, string, unicode, logic, logical-operators

```
public static boolean uniqueCheck(String s)
{
    int checker=0,val=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        val=s.charAt(i)-'a';
        if ((checker & (1<< val))>0) return false;
        checker |= (1<<val);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I want to know how this code will ignore space( ) and return true for unique character.
For an example: `"a b c d"` returns true. but space also has Unicode value, when it encounters space 2 times it should return false. Why not??

Comment: You should better describe what you want to achive. The code is right for `aa` but fail for `  ` (two spaces), because `s.charAt(i)-'a'` is negative why your `if-statement` fails.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use `replaceAll()` to replace all whitespaces (or any other characters that you specify) from your `string`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `1 << (' ' - 'a')` is negative, so the int extracted by the bitmask:

```
(checker & (1 << val))
```

is also negative.

Change the condition to

```
if ((checker & (1<< val)) != 0) return false;
                       // ^^ Here.
```

However: you've only got 32 bits to use to indicate the previous detection of a `char`, and there are 65536 possible values of `val`: this method will fail very quickly for other strings.

For example, the method would claim that `"Aa"`, `"R2"` and `" @"` (space, followed by at sign) have repeated characters, which is obviously wrong.

This only *happens* to work for `"a b c d"` because of the arrangement of ASCII codepoints - space just happens to not collide with any of the other symbols in the string, modulo 32.