# How do I check for special characters in a String[Java]?

Tags: java, string, console, java.util.scanner, user-input

I am creating a console game.. and I want the players to be able to choose their own usernames. Having usernames like **.-|\12b-}|** can be really weird. I want to be able to check if the username has "special characters" in it. If the player has a special character in his/her username, I want the system to print out a message(something like: *Please change your username)*. I don't want the code to just [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841179/check-for-unique-character-in-a-string-java) the letters.

**Here is an example(follow this if you have an answer):**

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
class StackOverflowExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome New Player! What will your name be?");
    Scanner userInteraction = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = userInteraction.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Welcome " + userInput + "!");
  }
}
```

**Output**:

[image: You can see why this would be a problem]

You can see why this would be super weird..

I want to be able to scan:

```
String userInput = userInteraction.nextLine();
```

for any weird characters. **How would I go about scanning the String?**

Comment: I believe a scanner can accept a regex as a parameter to validate a next() input. "a-zA-Z0-9_" would filter alphanumeric characters with underscores etc.

Comment: Doesn't seem like uniqueness is in any way a factor here...

Comment: @VLAZ unique characters are characters like "/" or "%"

Comment: Those are called "special characters". The term "unique" is almost exclusively meant to mean "non-repeating" in programming. So, the string `"abc"` contains unique characters but `"abca"` does not because `"a"` shows up twice.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks, its changed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  It continues to prompt for a username if anything other than letters are provided. Usernames like Battle101 or ~Hello~ are not allowed.

```
Scanner userInteraction = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = "";
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Welcome New Player! What will your name be?");
    userInput = userInteraction.nextLine();
    if (userInput.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) { // check that the input only contains letters
       // okay so exit loop
        break;
    }
    // else explain the problem and reprompt.
    System.out.println("Only alphabetic characters are permitted.\nPlease try again.");
}
System.out.println("Welcome " + userInput + "!");
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! What is the 'plus sign' doing in "[a-zA-Z]+"? Is it redundant?

Answer (score 2):

**Edited to have correct java code**

You can check what each letter in a string is by using a int-asted `charAt` call to return the # the character is in ASCII [See here] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)

```
public static boolean isAlphaNumeric(String str) {
  int code, i, len;
  len = str.length();
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    code = (int) str.charAt(i);
    if (!(code > 47 && code < 58) && // numeric (0-9)
        !(code > 64 && code < 91) && // upper alpha (A-Z)
        !(code > 96 && code < 123)) { // lower alpha (a-z)
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String userInput = userInteraction.nextLine();
   if(isAlphaNumeric(userInput )){
       System.out.println("Welcome New Player! What will your name be?");
       Scanner userInteraction = new Scanner(System.in);
       String userInput = userInteraction.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Welcome " + userInput + "!");
   }
   else{
      System.out.println("Change your name from" + userInput + "!");
   }}
```

Comment: Hi @StarshipladDev, I would like to clarify that this is **Java** not **JavaScript**. The code that you inputted was **JavaScript**.

Comment: @FairOPShotgun , I've updated, you may cast a char value as an int for the same ASCII value <3